# scroll view animation to prevent keyboard covering text field works in simulator but not on my phone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have a scroll view with a textField and textView and am using an animation to move the page up so the keyboard doesn't cover them when it pops up. It works perfectly  in my simulator on all phone sizes but when I try it on my iPhone it doesn't work at all. I'm not sure if I missed something or am doing something incorrectly. My code for the animation:

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 225), animated: true)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 75), animated: true)
}
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 25), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm puzzling. What is your `ScrollView.contentSize.height` set to?

Comment: Maybe that's part of the problem, i don't have it set in my VC like that, just on the storyboard Size Inspector and it's set to 800.

Comment: Thats the only possibility I can think of without seeing your whole project and I'm not usually one to lecture about this sort of thing but you should consider renaming your UIScrollView to `scrollView` instead of `ScrollView` for best practice as only ClassNames should be capitalized in this format

Comment: Thanks Garret I changed the name of the UIScrollView. Would setting my ScrollView.contentSize.height be "ScrollView.contentSize.height = 800"? Also It turns out it is scrolling but looks totally different on the simulator and on my phone. If the setContentOffset is set at a certain point shouldn't it look the same on all devices? For example in the simulator when I run this on iPhone 5 it lines up differently and some of the TextView and TextField are covered or in iPhone 6s Plus it's way lower than where it is on iPhone 6s, shouldn't they all be they same? I'm kind of new to Xcode.

Comment: The reason they are not in the same scroll position is because different devices have different screen sizes which is why most of the time positions are not what we call 'hard coded'. For example, setting the content offset on a UIScrollView to "800" is referred to as 'hard coding' because this value will not vary. What you want is something like `self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2), animated: true)` notice instead of the y value being something like "800" it will now be half of the superview's height on all devices.

Comment: Thanks Garret, is there a way to anchor it to a textview/textfield's bottom? I have a textfiled and textview so can you place the keyboard at the bottom of the each when that filed is tapped?